# Change the background colour of a projected Matplotlib axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to create a figure using Cartopy that requires a projected axis to be drawn over an unprojected axis.

Here is a simple as possible version of the code that substitutes content on the axes for background colour:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

#Setup figure
fig = plt.figure()

#Unprojected axis
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='b')

#Projected axis
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='None', projection=ccrs.Mercator())

plt.show()
```

Which instead of leaving the blue axis visible produces this:
[image]
Removing the `projection=ccrs.Mercator()` argument from the above code produces this expected result:
[image]

How do I make the projected axis background transparent?

Thanks!

Edit:
I've tried these other methods of setting the background transparent with no luck:

```
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='None', alpha=0, projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax2.patch.set_facecolor('none')
ax2.patch.set_alpha(0)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding ```alpha=0.5 ``` to the subplot params ? that should define the transparency levels. I cant seem to get cartopy set up with pip but this should work I think.

Comment: @FranciscoVargas Thanks for the suggestion-unfortunately I've tried experimenting with other transparency methods (see edits) but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cartopy is still not very well-rounded in terms of controlling some things, and I'm afraid you need to dig into the code to find some things out.

I think the basic tweak you need is this :

```
ax2.background_patch.set_fill(False)
```

My hacked example :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='b')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='None', projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax2.background_patch.set_fill(False)
ax2.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND)
ax2.coastlines(color='red', linewidth=0.75)
plt.show()
```

Picture : [image]

Edit: removed copy/paste error

HTH
Patrick

Comment: I have also found that I need to keep the axisbg='None' argument to keep the intended drawing order of the content of the axies (for some reason, taking it away didn't stop it being transparent...)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `imshow()` to project an image onto the background of your map. Cartopy uses the `stock_img()` method for this purpose.

You can also get a solid background colour, by creating a 2x2 pixel image with NumPy, and projecting it over the entire map extents:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.feature import LAND
    
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# Set RGB value to ocean colour
ax.imshow(np.tile(np.array([[[200, 200, 255]]], 
          dtype=np.uint8), [2, 2, 1]),
      origin='upper',
      transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
      extent=[-180, 180, -90, 90])

ax.add_feature(LAND)
ax.coastlines()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `extent=[-180, 180, -90, 90]`