# Cartopy background color (outside of data domain)

Tags: python, matplotlib, background, cartopy

In a Cartopy map, I would like to have the region not covered by any data (outside of my domain) colored in e.g. lightgrey.
Have played with `background_patch` and looked at this example [Change the background colour of a projected Matplotlib axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200438/change-the-background-colour-of-a-projected-matplotlib-axis) but still can't figure out to do what I want.

Here is an artificial example, where I make the domain bounds visible by a red line. Instead I would like to have the area outside of the red line colored in lightgrey.

Many thanks!

**EDIT:** 
Changed the projection to LambertConformal to demonstrate that the solution proposed below ([Cartopy background color (outside of data domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898312/cartopy-background-color-outside-of-data-domain/34989375#34989375)) does only work for rectangular grids. See additional figures below.
[image: The domain bounds drawn]
[image: The proposed solution]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import numpy as np

#create some lons/lats
lats = np.linspace(20,40,50)
lons = np.linspace(110,130,50)
lons,lats = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

#some data
thedata = np.zeros_like(lats)
#some 'cloud' in the data
thedata[5:8,7:13] = 1

#theproj = ccrs.Mercator()
theproj = ccrs.LambertConformal() #choose another projection to obtain non-rectangular grid
ef, axar = plt.subplots(1,1, subplot_kw={'projection': theproj})#, 'axisbg': 'w'
ef.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.,wspace=0.,bottom=0.05,top=0.95,left=0.03,right=0.98)    
axar.coastlines()

mycmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['white', 'black'])
bounds=[0,0.5,1]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, mycmap.N)

im = axar.pcolormesh(lons,lats,thedata,cmap=mycmap, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
im.set_norm(norm)

#make the extent larger to see a margin outside of the domain
axar.set_extent([lons[0,0]-1,lons[-1,-1]+1,lats[0,0]-1,lats[-1,-1]+1])


#for illustration: make the domain bounds visible
#but instead of the red domain bounds I would like to have the background (outside of the domain) in some color (lightgrey)
axar.plot(lons[:,0],lats[:,0],'r', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axar.plot(lons[:,-1],lats[:,0],'r', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axar.plot(lons[0,:],lats[0,:],'r', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axar.plot(lons[0,:],lats[-1,:],'r', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

#some decoration to see where we are
gl = axar.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                  linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER    

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, this can be achieved with matplotlib alone if you weren't using cartopy:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.path import Path
import numpy as np


# Create some lons/lats
lats = np.linspace(20,40,50)
lons = np.linspace(110,130,50)
lons,lats = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

# Some data with 'cloud'.
thedata = np.zeros_like(lats)
thedata[5:8, 7:13] = 1

ax = plt.axes()

mycmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(['white', 'black'])
bounds=[0, 0.5, 1]
norm = mcolors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, mycmap.N)

im = ax.pcolormesh(lons, lats, thedata, cmap=mycmap,
                   norm=norm)

data_extent = np.array((lons[0,0], lons[-1,-1], lats[0,0], lats[-1,-1]))

# Make the extent larger to see a margin outside of the domain
ax.set_xlim(data_extent[:2] + [-1, 1])
ax.set_ylim(data_extent[2:] + [-1, 1])

# Create a path which has the exterior of the map, with an interior of the data we care about.
path_with_hole = Path([[-180, 90],
                       [180, 90],
                       [180, -90],
                       [-180, -90],
                       [-180, 90],
                       [data_extent[0], data_extent[2]],
                       [data_extent[1], data_extent[2]],
                       [data_extent[1], data_extent[3]],
                       [data_extent[0], data_extent[3]],
                       [data_extent[0], data_extent[2]]],
                      codes=[Path.MOVETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO,
                             Path.MOVETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO])

geom = mpatches.PathPatch(path_with_hole, facecolor='lightgrey',
                          edgecolor='white',
                          hatch='xxxx', alpha=0.6)
ax.add_patch(geom, )

plt.show()
```

[image: figure_mpl]

The key is that we produce a Path which has the map as the exterior, and the domain we are interested in as the interior. We can that add that path to an axes by turning it into a patch (the things you actually see on a matplotlib figure).

We can use this technique in a cartopy figure in the obvious way:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.path import Path
import numpy as np


# Create some lons/lats
lats = np.linspace(20,40,50)
lons = np.linspace(110,130,50)
lons,lats = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

# Some data with 'cloud'.
thedata = np.zeros_like(lats)
thedata[5:8, 7:13] = 1

pc = ccrs.PlateCarree()
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax.coastlines()

# Some decoration to see where we are
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=pc,
                  draw_labels=True,
                  linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=0.5,
                  linestyle='--')
gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER

mycmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(['white', 'black'])
bounds=[0, 0.5, 1]
norm = mcolors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, mycmap.N)

im = ax.pcolormesh(lons, lats, thedata, cmap=mycmap,
                   norm=norm, transform=pc)

proj_extent = np.array(list(pc.x_limits) + list(pc.y_limits))
data_extent = np.array((lons[0,0], lons[-1,-1], lats[0,0], lats[-1,-1]))

# Make the extent larger to see a margin outside of the domain
ax.set_extent(data_extent + [-2, 2, -2, 2])

# Create a path which has the exterior of the map, with an interior of the data we care about.
path_with_hole = Path([[proj_extent[0], proj_extent[3]],
                       [proj_extent[1], proj_extent[3]],
                       [proj_extent[1], proj_extent[2]],
                       [proj_extent[0], proj_extent[2]],
                       [proj_extent[0], proj_extent[3]],
                       [data_extent[0], data_extent[2]],
                       [data_extent[1], data_extent[2]],
                       [data_extent[1], data_extent[3]],
                       [data_extent[0], data_extent[3]],
                       [data_extent[0], data_extent[2]]],
                      codes=[Path.MOVETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO,
                             Path.MOVETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO])

geom = mpatches.PathPatch(path_with_hole, facecolor='lightgrey',
                          edgecolor='white',
                          hatch='xxxx', alpha=0.6, transform=pc)
ax.add_patch(geom)

plt.show()
```

HTH

**EDIT:** Your questions specifically mentions LambertConformal, and the fact that this solution doesn't appear to work. It turns out, the problem is not with the solution, but with Cartopy's LambertConformal definition itself being of too low resolution.

The workaround is sadly pretty severe: it is necessary to override the LambertConformal projection and modify the magic number threshold. This should be far easier in the future.

```
class BetterLambertConformal(ccrs.LambertConformal):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ccrs.LambertConformal.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._threshold = 1e4

    @property
    def threshold(self):
        return self._threshold

ax = plt.axes(projection=BetterLambertConformal())
```

[image: cartopy figure]

Comment: Thanks for this proposed solution. My example was a bit too simplistic in the sense, that I would need a solution that also works for non-rectangular grids. See my edit above.

Comment: Actually, the code is fine (try Robinson). The problem you are seeing is with the resolution of LambertConformal. The resolution is currently hardcoded: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/8.